# DataFrame filter

Tags: python, pandas

What're the differences between these two ways of selecting certain columns?

I am using Python, pandas package

`df[['col1','col2','col3']]`

`df.filter(['col1','col2','col3'])`

The outputs are the same, but not sure any underlying difference that I should know.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact name of the column you need

```
df[['col1','col2','col3']]
```

If you want to using `regex` or `like`

```
df.filter(like='col')
```